# Separate sequential \tnote

Tags: threeparttablex, tnote

If I have two sequential `\tnote{}` tags they get morfed into one number, in the MVE below instead of having 1 and 2 I get 12, is there a way to visually separate these two notes?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{ThreePartTable}
  \begin{TableNotes}  %%% This should come before longtable and it is not tablenotes but TableNotes
  \small
  \item[1] first note
  \item[2] second note 
  \end{TableNotes}
\begin{longtable}{rr}
  \caption{My caption}\label{mytbl}\\
  \toprule
  City & Country \\
  \midrule
  \endhead

\midrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes         %% this added
\endlastfoot

  London & UK \tnote{1} \tnote{2} \\

  %\bottomrule
  \end{longtable}
  \end{ThreePartTable}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/388384/134144 might be useful.

Comment: thanks, somehow a bit cumbersome but it will do the trick